# Image messes up div that has a height of 100%

Tags: html, css

My main content box has a height of 100%. Every time I try to place an image at the bottom of the div, it does not extend like it will with text. (I used min-height:100%;)
[image: Before Placing an image]

But once I place my image, it appears like this:

[image]

Here is my code I'm working with:

```
.MainContent {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #bdc3c7;
}
```

And for my image...

```
<img src="JBbio.jpg" style="width:363px;height:465px;transform:scale(0.7); float: left;">
```

Comment: your image has the float property, add a clearfix to the div and it should be extending as desired. Also, take those inline styles out and put in your .css file, if possible.

Comment: @Flignats I've tried multiple clearfix methods, but so far none of them are working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `overflow: hidden`on your `MainContent`